# How to make dualboot (2 linux distros)

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

Can someone give me a step-by-step guidance how can I install on my laptop(that has one hard drive) 2 linux distros(Kali linux and lubuntu 16.04)?
I'm stuck with partitioning. How should I separate my drive?
My purpose is to give for Kali linux 50 Gb of space and rest for Lubuntu. Then i suppose to see GRUB on boot, where I can select an OS I like to launch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case you are not separately looking a separate harddisk partition for your folders under your Linux distribution (For eg: separate partition for /home /usr /etc). I am assuming you are already aware as to how to install Linux and using gparted etc.

Install your first OS suppose Kali. In the partition details window select Manual. Create three partitions 50 Gb ext4 for Kali (here set the mount pint as '/' without quotes, keep aside 4 Gb for SWAP, format your third partition whatever space is left as ext4. Install and boot Kali. Verify Kali works and you have your three partitions.

Now for next OS, in a similar fashion insert your bootable USB or disc for Lubuntu, at the partition prompt choose manual. Now select your third partition, and set the mount point as / (This is the root for Linux/Unix). No need to touch any other partition. Just continue setting your username, password or other settings if any. Wait for Lubuntu to install. Once done reboot and you should see entries for Kali and Lubuntu in Grub Menu.

If for some reason Kali or Lubuntu's entry is not available in grub and it directly loads the OS. Here is what you can do:

1) If Lubuntu directly boots:
Open a terminal and write the following command:

`$ sudo update-grub`

2) If Kali directly boots:
Since Kali Linux is based on debian, the same command for Lubuntu should work fine.

That should generate the grub and on next reboot you should be able to see the grub with entries for both OSes.

Comment: Hey, man, thank you for your reply. Here is a little question: what types of first and third partitions should I select? AFAIR, there are primary and logical.

Comment: A disk with a traditional partition table can only have up to four partitions. Extended and logical partitions are a way to get around this limitation.

Each disk can have up to four primary partitions or three primary partitions and an extended partition.
Let’s say you want six partitions on a single drive. You’d have to create three primary partitions as well as an extended partition. The extended partition functions as a container that allows you to create a larger amount of logical partitions.

[More Info](http://www.howtogeek.com/184659/beginner-geek-hard-disk-partitions-explained/)

Comment: I hope that helps :)